# Add a space between certain rows in a listview

Tags: android, listview, row, adapter, space

I have a listview whose each row is made of several texts. One of them is a group name that I display when it's different from the one before. In the same time, I want to create a space to separate the categories for a best appearance. So I added a padding in the getView method of my baseAdapter like indicated between ** **:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
        R.layout.ir_item, parent, false);
}

TextView group = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.data1);
TextView range = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.data2);
TextView assignment = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.data3);
LinearLayout linear = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.line); //it's the linearlayout parent of rows

HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(position);
if (position > 0) {
    if (item.get(GROUP).equals(getItem(position - 1).get(GROUP))) {
    group.setText("");
    } else {
    **linear.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);**
    group.setText(item.get(GROUP));
    }
} else {
    group.setText(item.get(GROUP));
}
range.setText(item.get(RANGE) + " (" + item.get(INTENSITY) + ")");
assignment.setText(item.get(ASSIGNMENT));

return convertView;
}}
```

It works fine for the first page, but when I scroll the list, or I come back.... the padding is created on all the rows, and I lose the space effect. Yet, the group name is not written everywhere, although the code line appears in the same condition.

I can't find where the problem is, could you help me ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapter supports multiple viewtypes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Implement getItemViewType & getViewTypeCount then in getView call getItemViewType  and based on the response create the correct view.

here is an example that uses the functionality to give each line a different color:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView

Comment: Thanks, I followed your example and another, and now it's perfect